# How does Linux generate ssh keys after reboot?

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

I installed CentOS 7, and noticed that I have rsa and ecdsa keys generated. I deleted all of them and rebooted the machine. I got a new pair of rsa and ecdsa keys.

How does Linux generate the keys? When is ssh-keygen called..? I couldn't find the configuration for this...

Comment: Could you give more precision about the keys? Where the keys are generated? Which keys?

Comment: I do not think Linux does anything like this on boot. It is likely that you have some service installed (eg. Docker deamon) which is generating a keypair for you.

Comment: @Ketan RHEL does actually generate the ssh keypair on boot if the ID files don't already exist. It's part of the `/etc/init.d/sshd` script on RHEl5 and RHEL6. I just don't know how RHEL7 works well enough to answer this question.

Answer (score 2):

sshd's daemon is started by `/etc/init.d/sshd` (more precisely from a link located in /etc/rc$x.d ).

upon starting sshd, a check is made over existence of key files. if those file are missing `ssh-keygen` will be call.

Comment: This is on RHEL7 which is going to have a `systemd` system of initialization. The script you reference is for SysVinit.